# Detect fixed length tuple type vs. array type in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have a generic function and I would like to make it accept only fixed length (possibly mixed type) tuples as the type argument. I do not know the possible tuple types in advance - it should accept any fixed length tuples.

```
doSomething<[number, string, boolean]>(); // this should be okay
doSomething<number[]>(); // this should throw a compiler error
```

I know that I can restrict the length to a specific number literal (array check omitted for brevity):

```
type LengthOf<N extends number> = {
  length: N;
}
function doSomething<T extends LengthOf<2>(){};
doSomething<[any, any]>(); // ok
doSomething<[any]>(); // error
```

But I can't use this method to restrict the length to *any* number literal, since any number literal will extend number and that's also the `length` type of variable length arrays.

Is this possible in TypeScript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure why you want this, but you could strengthen the [generic constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) so that it will only accept array types whose `length` property is narrower than `number`:

```
function doSomething<
    T extends (number extends T['length'] ? [] : any[])
>() { };
```

This will allow fixed-length tuples or ones whose length is a union of numeric literals like [tuples with optional elements](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#optional-elements-in-tuple-types),

```
doSomething<[number, string, boolean]>(); // okay
doSomething<[number, string, boolean?]>(); // okay
```

while disallowing arrays or open-ended tuples (with [rest elements](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#rest-elements-in-tuple-types)):

```
doSomething<number[]>(); // error
doSomething<[number, string, ...boolean[]]>(); // error
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.3#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAEzgZTgWwKZQBYxgDmAPALABQi1iAKotgB5TZjIDOiAFGCJgEbYATg2asOdANoByADasi+aQF1EAfkSTVALkQBDMAE8tASkoA+LicQBvRAF8A3JUqoMOfIVKTeA4QBpEdighL0D+ODh5A2VLE0dEAHpExDgAaz1DV3QsXAJiEh8+QSFA4NDicMjosDVYqwTk1Iysimz3PK8SXxKtOMaU4SE4IXbczwKiv1LEADp58q8tevikwaFh0baKIA)